# Slided Container Moves Despite Calculated Widths

Tags: html, css

One of my recent projects includes the use of two containers next to each other. When a button is pressed, I want the content container (basically a false body) to reduce it's width and the the menu container to be able to move in.

I seem to mostly get it to work, though the transition can't be seamless without some JS tom-foolery (which really voids the aesthetic). On the far right (the area where the menu will be most of the time), the menu moves down, though there's no margins.

[image: The menu container moving down.]

This makes no sense to me, and adding no amount of translation nor reducing the width of either containers seems to fix it. Am I missing something?

HTML

```
<body>
    <main>
        <p>Container.</p>
    </main>
    <aside>
        <p>Menu.</p>
    </aside>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
main {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    width: 100%;
}
aside {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid red;
    transform: translate(450px, 0px);
    width: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious. Main and aside are in two different rows.

I've made a variation of code ;p.

HTML:

```
<body>
<section>
    <main>
        <p>Container.</p>
    </main>
    <aside>
        <p>Menu.</p>
    </aside>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
main {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    width: calc(100% - 454px);
    display: inline-block;
}
aside {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 450px;
}
section {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% + 450px);
    float: left;
}
```

I hope that this will help in something.